# Troubleshooting TrueCrypt AES pretest errors

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

Every time I try full system encryption with truecrypt (AES) I'm getting a 'pretest failed' message after my test reboot. The thing is, nothing actually fails, I get a password prompt from the boot loader, windows start correctly first time.

I'm using a samsung 1TB HDD with NTFS, AES encryption, 7 Pass US DoD 5220, default hash algorithm.

I'm really lost when it comes to looking at ways to by pass this but I do genuinely need my system encrypted.

[image]

Error message

Comment: Were you using an algorithm other than AES?  Please post a screenshot of the settings used.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I can't find a single result on Google about how to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?

Comment: This test is unrelated to AES or encryption. It's just a test whether the bootloader works, because you'd be (almost) SOL if it didn't after encrypting your system.

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue - turned out the problem was 100Mb boot partition - it was located on another HDD! I marked Windows partition as active, deleted that other one - and everything worked well.

Comment: This only works if there's a copy of the Windows Boot Manager installed. `bcdboot` is an all-in-one command to install it.